# MM74C933N Output-enabled pin

Tags: integrated-circuit, output, encoder

Studying the datasheet of the [MM74C922N 4x4 matrix keypad](https://www.soemtron.org/downloads/disposals/74c922.pdf) and I am lost on what the output-enabled pin does, its function, and why it is needed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why is the datasheet explanation not good and you need another one? If the explanation uses concepts you don't understand, then ask or search about those concepts instead. There has been a lot of 74C922 questions during the past few days for some mysterious reasons - perhaps this is a school assignment to write how this chip works? Can you search for them and see if they already answer your questions?

Comment: I mean, I have researched and found out that output enable controls the output between 3 states on, off, or high impedance. But I still don't get what that does in this particular case

Comment: Do you understand the concept of a data bus?

Comment: A system that transfers data between components?

Comment: @BeatriceUK We don't know what specific case or context you mean. The chip has output enable control like many other chips do. In some contexts you must use it, it some contexts it is irrelevant. So if you don't understand why you need it in your context, maybe the context does not need it? Can you say what your context is for using that chip?

Comment: I mean there isn't really any context behind this, just studying this component. I guess I can ask in what situations is it used in?

Comment: @BeatriceUK Data buses but that is already mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try, but I'm slightly confused by your question:

> what the output-enabled pin does, its function

It enables the output! See "Theory of Operation":

> The output latches feed 3-STATE, which is enabled when the Output Enable (OE) input is taken low.

"3-State" means the outpus can be high, low, or a third state, and that means (in basically all relevant contextes) "high impedance" (nearly floating around).

So, if you pull O̅U̅T̅P̅U̅T̅ ̅E̅N̅A̅B̅L̅E̅ high, you're disabling the output, which means A, B, C, D, and E look as if they've been disconnected.

> why it is needed

In a data bus, there might be multiple devices that need to define the voltage (or current) on a line. Imagine four of your chips being wired to the same A – E lines, so that a single microcontroller with 5 inputs can deal with them.

Now, only one IC must ever put voltage on the common lines (imagine where the current flows if the first IC pulls line A high, the second IC pulls A low). So, if you have a data bus, all but at most one IC are in high-impedance state, and the one IC that isn't can define whether a line is high or low.

Comment: What does it mean when an output is "High Impedance"?

Comment: it means it looks as if the output is floating around, i.e. it's disconnected internally.